# WinSCP batch script is not is not downloading latest file

Tags: winscp

I'm using the "-latest" switch but it's only downloading the oldest file rather then latest "newest". Files file are in ascending order, ever new file/generation is +1 see sample below.

Files
G3160V00
G3161V00
G3162V00
G3163V00
G3164V00

Currently when I run the script it downloads the oldest "G3160V00", where I'm expecting the latest "G3164V00" not sure if it possible to download based on filename.

Current script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\FTPtemp\FTPtesting\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@sc01/ -rawsettings ProxyPort=0" ^
    "cd 'KINP.EDI.BI04801.'" ^
    "lcd C:\FTPtemp\FTPtesting" ^
    "get -latest *" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

This is the script used before moving over to WinSCP, this one would download only the latest file.

```
@ftp -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open sc01
user
password
lcd C:\FTPtemp\FTPtesting
prompt
cd ..
cd KINP.EDI.
mget BI04801(0)
bye
```

Comment: Post a session log file please.

Comment: The `-latest` selects the latest file by timestamp. Do you want to select the last file alphabetically (lexicographically) instead?

Comment: i guess that would be the option i would have to go with, as timestamp isn't working out for me. but even that doesn't seem straightforward or am i missing something?

Comment: That's unclear to me. So do you expect the timestamps to work? Do the files have timestamps by which WinSCP should be able to identify the latest file? In that case please post the log file. – Or is it impossible to choose the right file by the timestamps? Do you really need to use the file name to identify the "latest" files?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i myself am fairly new to this system. So to my understanding the file system doesn't store timestamps, so filename is my only option. I update OP to include script that was working before attempting to use WinSCP.

Comment: Why would the `mget BI04801(0)` download the lastest file? What does `BI04801(0)` have to do with your files named like `G3160V00`? Is that some special feature of your FTP server? Is it some mainframe system?

Comment: BI04801 is path of the file path, yes it's a mainframe system.

Comment: Thanks. Though that does not answer my first question.